# Disproportionality vs disproportionalities

Tags: uncountable-nouns

Should one use **disproportionality** or **disproportionalities**? Is only one option correct or are both correct? If both options work, what is the difference and which option is more idiomatic?

> There is **disproportionality** between the elements of the system.

> There are **disproportionalities** between the elements of the system.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct.  Are there a series of separate issues with one part not being proportional to another, or is there a general problem distributed throughout the system?

Is "disproportionality" actually the right word? How would the system be better if parts were proportional to each other?  This feels like you are being sesquipedalian.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what the intended sense here is, but *idiomatically* I'd say two particularly common nouns for the context are ***discrepancies*** and ***inconsistencies***. Even if in principle I knew that ***disproportionalities*** was a more precise term for exactly what I was talking about, I'd still rather use one of those two common alternatives, simply to avoid the text looking a bit weird.